# Overloading "+"-operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the + operator in C++, but get the following error:

> operators.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   operators.cpp: 23:17: error: cannot convert ‘Operators’ to ‘int’ in initialization

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Operators{
    private:
        int num1;

    public:
        Operators(int num1){
            this->num1 = num1;
        }
        Operators operator+(Operators o){
            return Operators(num1 + o.num1);
        }
};

int main(){
    Operators o1(5);
    Operators o2(10);
    Operators res = o1 + o2; // EDITED

    cout << res;
}
```

Could you please help me?

I know, in this case it doesn't make sense to overload it, as I could just say `5+10`, but I'm just experimenting.

**UPDATE**
Thanks, I've edited the `int`.
But now I'm getting the following error:

> operators.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   operators.cpp: 25:10: error: match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << res’
>   [...]

Comment: Your edit has changed the question completely. You shouldn't do that. If you have a different question, then ask a different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this line:

```
int res = o1 + o2;
```

Is that your overload of `operator +` returns an object of type `Operators`. This means that you are trying to initialize an `int` (`res)` from a temporary of type `Operators` (the result of `o1 + o2`), but there is no user-defined conversion for doing that.

This is why the compiler is issuing an error. You can fix this easily by adding a conversion operator to your `Operators` class:

```
operator int () const { return num1; }
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems you have updated your question. The second line below is problematic:

```
Operators res = o1 + o2;
cout << res;
```

Unless you defined an overload of `operator <<` for your `Operators` class, the compiler won't know which overload of `operator <<` to pick for streaming your object of type `Operators`.

To solve the issue, you can:

- Define a conversion operator to `int`, as suggested above
- Define an overload of `operator <<` for `Operators`, as follows:

  ```
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, Operators const& op)
  {
      o << op.num1;
      return o;
  }
  ```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/RWWYyW).

Comment: Thanks, it works now! But what is that line for `operator int () { return num1; }`?

Comment: @user1170330: That is the conversion operator. It allows implicitly converting an object of type `Operators` into an `int`

Comment: And what if I have several numbers, like `int num1, num2, num3;`?

Comment: @user1170330: I do not understand this last question

Answer (score 3):

As the error message is trying to tell you, `o1 + o2` is of type `Operators`.
You can't assign that to an `int`

Comment: @user1170330: You do not have an overload of `operator <<` for `Operators`, nor a conversion operator from `Operators` to `int`. My answer should solve your problem.

Comment: Dumb question, but why do I need to overload <<? I only want to add the two numbers, so I only overloaded +.

Comment: @user1170330: What do you expect `cout << res` to do? And how?

Comment: @user1170330: The compiler can't "magically" understand that it has to insert into `cout` the member `num1` of your `Operators` object. Either you provide a conversion operator to some type that standard overloads of `operator <<` can handle (e.g. `int`), or you provide an overload of `operator <<` that can work with objects of type `Operators`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator+` returns an `Operators` object. You then try and assign this result to `int res`. YOu have given no way to convert from an `Operators` object to an `int`. You could provide a conversion operator to do this:

```
operator int() {
  return num1;
}
```

This defines a conversion from `Operators` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `int` to `Operators`, and implement your own copy and default constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

class Operators
{
    private:
        int num1;

    public:
        Operators() = default;
        Operators(Operators const& op) : num1(op.num1) {}
        Operators(int num1)
        {
            this->num1 = num1;
        }
        Operators operator+(Operators o)
        {
            return num1 + o.num1;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Operators o1(5);
    Operators o2(10), res;

    res = o1 + o2;

    std::cout << res;
}
```

To make this work further, create an overload of `operator<<` and print the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write:

```
int res = o1.getMethod() + o2.getMethod();
```

where getMethod() is a public method in your class that returns the private integer num1.
Otherwise, you don't have access to it. Try it.